# Is there a phrase or word that means "put on too much makeup"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a phrase or word that means "put on too much makeup"? I remember there was a phrase and I think it had the word "paste" in it, but I don't remember it. I also think there was a verb that pretty much meant the same thing, but I don't remember it either. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usually if there is a lot of make-up that someone has put on, and you can clearly tell, it could be described as **"caked on"**

Answer (score 1):

“You look like a clown” is a pretty offensive thing that’s said when someone’s wearing too much makeup. If you’ve ever seen a clown, it’s pretty obvious why people say this: [clowns often wear face paint](https://www.partycity.com/jumbo-clown-wig-178073.html) that that looks like poorly done makeup.

Examples in use:

- [How To Easily Apply Red Lipstick Without Feeling Like You Look Like A Clown](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/how-to-easily-apply-red-lipstick-without-feeling-like-you-look-like-a-clown-2952146)
- [MUA advice, think I look like a clown](https://weddingwire.com/wedding-forums/mua-advice-think-i-look-like-a-clown/103aa4539e922e92.html)
- [Why do I look like a clown with makeup?](https://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/style_and_beauty/3467818-why-do-i-look-like-a-clown-with-makeup)

Answer (score 0):

Like putty or painted like a clown like too much foundation or too dark and too much and messy. Dark foundationputty and loud and screaming colors. It looks messy irregular it looks not natural.It is too much of everything.

Comment: I'm having difficulty reading your answer. Could you [edit] your post to correct the punctuation and grammar? We expect answers to be models of proper English.